# Does PCA centering guarantee projection optimality onto an affine set subject to dimensionality constraint?

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, svd

Say I have $m$ points in $R^n$, not necessarily with sum 0, and I want to project them onto an affine set $S$ with $\dim(S)=d$ for a given $d$ so as to minimize the sum of the squared distances between the $m$ points and their corresponding projections. If I were looking for the optimum *vector subspace* of dimension $d$, then Eckart-Young theorem would guarantee that taking the subspace spanned by the $d$ principal components is optimal. Note that the difference is that the latter restricts the affine set to pass through the origin. Normally, when we perform PCA, we center the data and then look for a subspace, thus actually looking for an affine set passing through the mean of the $m$ points.

So my question is: is there any proof that the answer to my initial question always passes through the mean value? Can one prove that minimizing the sum of squared distances from points to their projections onto $S$ subject to $S$ being an affine set of dimension $d$ is reached for some $S$ that passes through the mean value? Or, equivalently, is it that centering the data guarantees optimal projection cost?

Here by affine set I mean an $S \subseteq R^n$ s.t. for any $a, b \in S$ and any $\lambda \in R$, we also have that $\lambda a + (1-\lambda)b \in S$, which is basically a vector subspace + translation.

Comment: If you truly wish to "to minimize the sum of the distances between the m points and their corresponding projections," then no form of PCA will do that.  If you wish to minimize the sum of *squared* distances, then you can decompose that into the sum of squares for the solution through the mean plus the square of something else and your proof is complete.

Comment: Yeah, sorry meant squared distances (edited now). I don't think I follow: it's not like the optimal solution must be parallel to that you'd get if you constrained $S$ to pass through the mean (as translating the points would yield different principal directions), so I really don't see how I could relate an arbitrary solution to the one passing through the mean (or the SVD of the matrix vs that of centered matrix)

Comment: Ahh, nevermind, I got what you meant. Basically you can prove that any affine set $S$ is no better than the parallel one going through the mean - thought you were actually relating it to the optimal solution that goes through the mean which you can't directly say much about. So this implies that there is an optimal $S$ going through the mean. Thanks!